# Array of Objects of one class embedded in another class + constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have 3 classes as shown below:

```
class A
{
  public:
    char * buf;
};

class C
{
  public:
   A * _ptrToA;

  private:
   func1();
};

class B
{
  public:
    A * _ptrToA;

  private:
    C  objsOfC[10];

};
```

What is missing here is that for every 10 objects of class C in class B, ptrtoA needs to be assigned.How can i assign the value to all 10 objects?

Also how/when will the constructor for the 10 objects be called.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Do you know what a constructor is and how to write one?

Comment: Yes i do know. But i must admit i am new to c++ coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class C has a constructor:

```
C() : _ptrToA(new A) 
{
}
```

then it will be automatically called (for all 10 objects C) when object of class B is created.

As general note: do not use pointers like that without smart pointers, and learn about constructors.

Comment: Its not that i want to create 10 new objects of A and assign them to 10 objects of class C. I am creating just one object of class A and i want all ten objects of class C point to the same Object of class A.

Comment: In this case use a constructor of class B with A* argument: B(A* ptr) : _ptrToA(ptr) { for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) objsOfC[i]._ptrToA = ptr; }

Comment: Will try doing that. Thanks for the quick reply!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor in C like

```
C(A * ptrToA)
{
    _ptrToA = ptrToA;
}
```

Then, create a constructor in B like,

```
B(A * ptrToA) : objsOfC({ C(ptrToA), C(ptrToA), C(ptrToA), C(ptrToA), C(ptrToA), C(ptrToA), C(ptrToA), C(ptrToA), C(ptrToA), C(ptrToA)  })
{
}
```

But this would be a total mess when you have an object array of hundreds in size.

Then it would be wise to have an object pointer array

If so, you have to change your code to something like,

class B
{

```
A * _ptrToA;
C ** objsOfC;
```

public:

```
B(A * ptrToA, const int size) :_ptrToA(ptrToA), objsOfC(new C*[size])
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        objsOfC[i] = new C(ptrToA);
}
```

};

It's up to you to de-allocate memory when needed.

Comment: Or just provide a default constructor for `C` instead of introducing potential leaks all over the place.

Comment: Yes. we could do so. But, then to assign pointer value (ptrToA) to created objects we have to provide a set method (or just dumbly set pointer value of each object) in a loop. According to the initial post, for me, it seems he/she needs assign the pointer value when the objects being created.